# How to Implement Game Center Leaderboard ID in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I'm trying to implement a leaderboard in one of my games using swift and I know that my code for implementing the leaderboard is correct, but I'm not sure how to write the leaderboard ID. The ID I created is FRHS1. Should I use "FRHS1", "com.______.FRHS1" or the number that iTunes Connect assigned, which is "55341796".

Thanks!

Comment: You should create Leaderboard in Itunes Connect then you will get the leaderboard ID there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose arbitrary (unique) strings as leaderboard IDs and assign them in iTunes Connect. Mine look like this: `leaderboard.identifier = "com.domain.app.leaderboard"`.

[image]

Comment: In that field, I just typed in "FRHS1" and not "com.domain.app.leaderboard". Can I just use FRHS1, or should I delete that leaderboard and create one using your syntax?

Comment: @StephenVondenstein try it: it will work with "FRHS1" as well.